# When should I utilize DriverOptions at the selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

When should I utilize DriverOptions at the selenium C#?

Example:

```
public void test(){
      DriverOptions capacidades;

}
```

This replaced the DesiredCapabilities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DriverOptions` itself is an abstract class, and as such, you'd rarely use it directly, and likely only reference if you are creating an abstracted method that will accept an inheriting concrete as a parameter (eg. some sort of browser agnostic startup method). 
See class documentation here: https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_DriverOptions.htm

Selenium also provides a number of implementations - it looks like one for each browser driver that is supported. The inheritance hierarchy is listed at the link above. You can specify things like command line arguments, the file path for the browser exe, extensions to install, and so on, to customize the particular browser process instance you are looking for.

EDIT:
To specifically address `DesiredCapabilities` vs `DriverOptions` - yes, you are correct, `DriverOptions` is effectively a replacement for `DesiredCapabilities`. The couple of links below indicate that it is preferred to use the `DriverOptions` implementation if it is available in the SDK you are using, whereas not `DesiredCapabilities` is the backup option for clients that have not provided such implementations, such as ruby (at the time of this answer).

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities

https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/23559/what-is-the-difference-between-desiredcapabilities-chromeoptions-and-when-to-u

Comment: I understood, my question arose as to why DesiredCapabilities will be discontinued. With that, I was in doubt what I will use to replace.

Comment: @RenatoSantana I see - I apologize, I didn't realize that was the specific focus of your question. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Excellent clarified my doubts totally. I was pretty confused because I upgraded to selenium 3.14 and is indicating as discontinued.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on David Jetter's answer I can give a specific driver implementation example. 
I store chrome options in the App.config like:

```
<!-- Chrome browser settings for web driver  OPTIONAL -->
<!-- https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/chrome_switches.cc -->
<add key="chrome:setting1" value="--window-size=1600,1100" />
<add key="chrome:setting2" value="--window-position=2150,5" />
<add key="chrome:setting3" value="--headless" />
```

and then do something like this in the Test base class:

```
    var options = new ChromeOptions();
    // Set all options from the app.config
    foreach (string key in ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys.Where(k => k.StartsWith("chrome:setting")))
        options.AddArgument(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key]);

    driver = new OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver(options);
```

So you can see that you can set the default window size and position, set if you want headless mode; there are several options you can implement.

Comment: Excellent idea, I'll try to practice it this way.